# Teradata - Find the records that are inserted in specific time zone

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a requirement to identify the time zone of a record (from a time stamp or date column) from existing populated table.  Can you please help me on this.

To be clear, we have a table on a server on which the records are inserted from different countries which have different time zone, I need to find what are all the records that are inserted by specific country (time zone).

I believe all the records are converted to time zone of the server while inserting.

The column is defined as "timestamp with time zone"  Also, is there any possibility to find the same information from only a timestamp column.

Thanks,
Cheeli

Comment: So it's impossible to convert all your times to the same time zone (e.g. UTC) when they're added to the table?

Comment: Of course you can't get the timezone from a timestamp without time zone or from a date. Regarding the existing data, there's a timezone already, so what do you really want? EST/CET/IST instead of -05:00/+01:00/+05:30?

Comment: no way to find timezone from timestamp create a column as 
    timestamp with timezone 
in your table and store timezone there.